# SQL server can not accept median function

Tags: sql-server

I wrote this Median function but it is executing with errors.. Can someone guide me what's wrong in the code?

```
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #ITEMORDERDETAILS
      (
         ITEM   CHAR(15),
         QTYSHP DECIMAL(21, 6),
         RQDATE DATETIME
      )

    DECLARE @Median FLOAT
    DECLARE @ITEM CHAR(15)
    DECLARE @ORDERCNT INT

    SET @ITEM=@ITEMN

    INSERT #ITEMORDERDETAILS
    SELECT ITEM,
           QTYSHP,
           RQDATE
    FROM   tbl123456
    WHERE  PRICE != '0'
           AND SALESMN != 'WB'
           AND RQDATE > ( getdate () - 180 )
           AND ITEM = @ITEM
    UNION
    SELECT ITEM,
           QTYSHP,
           RQDATE
    FROM   tbl123
    WHERE  PRICE != '0'
           AND SALESMN != 'WB'
           AND RQDATE > ( getdate () - 180 )
           AND ITEM = @ITEM

    SELECT @ORDERCNT = count (1)
    FROM   #ITEMORDERDETAILS

    --SELECT @ORDERCNT
    SELECT @Median = ( sum(QTYSHP) / @ORDERCNT )
    FROM   #ITEMORDERDETAILS

    SELECT @Median AS 'Median'

    --SELECT * from #ITEMORDERDETAILS
    DROP TABLE #ITEMORDERDETAILS

    RETURN @Median
END
```

ERRORS

> Msg 2772, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
> f_Get_Average_Order_Size_Median, Line 34 Cannot access temporary
> tables from within a function.
>
> Msg 2772, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
> f_Get_Average_Order_Size_Median, Line 35 Cannot access temporary
> tables from within a function.
>
> Msg 2772, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
> f_Get_Average_Order_Size_Median, Line 42 Cannot access temporary
> tables from within a function.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
> f_Get_Average_Order_Size_Median, Line 46 Incorrect syntax near the
> keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: **Cannot access temporary tables from within a function**

Comment: `@table` variables can be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is in your error message:

```
Line 34 Cannot access temporary tables from within a function
```

If you make a function, there are limits to what you can access.

However, if you use SQL Server **2012**, you do not need to write your own median function but you can use [PERCENTILE_DISC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231327.aspx)

```
PERCENTILE_DISC (0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY XXXX) 
                      OVER (PARTITION BY YYYY) AS Median
```